# How to Wipe Only C drive and reinstall Windows 10 OS?

Tags: windows, windows-10

my laptop became a bit slow and explorer crashes often. So, to clean install, I am guessing "Reset this PC" should work.
There are 2 options "Keep my files" and "remove everything". I have partitioned the hard drive space it to 4 local disks and installed windows 10 on C drive. I want only C drive to be cleaned and rest of the disks data to be intact. Which option to choose?

Additional Info: My laptop came with Windows 8 and I upgraded to W10. So I am hoping this reset option wouldn't mess with activation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want wipe all the data's from C drive make it as a fresh install you need to choose Reset option, While doing this you will be asked two options in that select first one

> Only the drive where windows is installed

Refer this image

[image]

Comment: Hi, I can select this as the answer if you could also comment on whether if it affects activation

Comment: Just now i tried with my test laptop which has Windows 8.1, After reset activation was not affected. After selecting the option (Only the drive where Windows is installed) select Just remove the files option.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same last week. So while my memory is fresh

1. You dont need to worry about activation. The PC wont need Windows 10 key because its already activated. Even after you do a reset.
2. Reset option allows you to clean the drive where Windows is installed and wipe everything. This affects only the partition where Windows is installed. In your case it is C drive so thats what you should choose.

Also read [How to Reset Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4130-reset-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 1):

One word of caution - I am unsure of how a recovery partition effects the Reset.
If ur unit has a recovery partition, it came with the computer. This recovery partition is used to do a "system recovery" which puts the unit back to the way it was when u bought it -- windows 8.
U need to verify that the RESET is going to reinstall W10, or u need to create a USB or DVD of W10 and do a clean install that way, which is the way I do it.